# angular 6 variable or method binding in *ngIf

Tags: angular, variable-binding

Is there any difference between binding a variable and binding a method in template *ngIf.

Ex:

**Case 1:**

```
<div *ngIf="myVar">ABC</div>
```

**Case 2:**

```
<div *ngIf="myFunction()">ABC</div>

myFunction() : boolean {
   if (cond1 && cond2 && cond3) {
       return true;
   } else { 
       return false;
   }
}
```

Is there any impact on performance?

I am trying to use the 2 case, getting range Error: Maximum call stack exceeds.

Help me on this? Thanks

Comment: If you want to know how much trouble you might be in if you use a function - try adding `console.count()` inside of it, and see how many times it will be called.

Comment: It is calling thousands of time.

Comment: That's exactly why you don't do that. Angular change detection will go through it again and again.

Comment: If i want to do multiple condition checks like *ngIf="cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && con4". it will be very big line in the template i want to avoid that type of coding. Is there any way?

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is

The first one wont have any performance issue since you are directly checking against a variable while the second one will have since angular uses change detection and it fires many times

Answer (score 4):

When u call a function angular fire the change detection cycle every time. better to use a get property

```
<div *ngIf="myvar">ABC</div>

get myvar() : boolean {
  if (cond1 && cond2 && cond3) {
    return true;
  } 
  return false;
}
```

Comment: In template i dont want to keep multiple condition checks, like <div *ngIf="cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && cond4">ABC</div>. So i started using method in *ngIf. That makes my code neat and clean.

Comment: What about in this case *ngIf="myFunction(arg1,arg2)" ?

Comment: then i would get the error `getting range Error: Maximum call stack exceeds.`

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka what makes you think that getters don't create the same performance issue?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do to avoid performance issue is that you can make a class variable

public myVar = cond1 && cond2 && cond3

and then you can use it in first option and maintain readability of the code