# Performance of calling standard built-in methods in Angular template

Tags: angular

I've read that using methods in angular templates can result in performance issues even if they're simple methods ([Can Calling Simple Methods in Angular Component Templates Cause Performance Issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58396544/can-calling-simple-methods-in-angular-component-templates-cause-performance-issu)).  Does that apply to ECMAScript defined standard built-in objects and functions (JSON, Math, Array methods, parseInt, decodeURI, etc.)?

For example, is it a problem if `trees` is an array and I used `join()` like this:

```
  <div>{{ trees.join(', ') }}</div>
```

Do I still need to use pipes (or some other strategy)?

Comment: Any method call is considered to be not performant, no matter what method and how "standard" it is. The main reason for it is the way change detection works: It just compares object identities and usually every method call returns a *brand new object*. Even when the object's properties have the same values, the objects are considered to be different and re-rendering is going to happen. That's the short story about why we don't call (any) methods inside templates.

Comment: Cool. I was hoping angular might know if a "standard" method is a pure function and kinda act like a pipe.  I guess not.

Comment: I don’t think your example is problematic. Angular holds a reference to ‘trees’ and as long as that reference doesn’t change, angular will not need to do another call to it. So basically, I disagree with the first comment, but only for these specific cases. In general, calling (component) methods from your template IS a bad idea.